# Non-constant variable in select case statement

Tags: fortran

Suppose I have the following piece of code in my Fortran program:

```
recursive function T_GreCoDi( n, m ) result (GCD)
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: n, m
  integer :: GCD

  select case(n)
    case(0)
      select case(m)
        case(0)
          print *, 'both of your numbers are zeros. GCD = -1'
          GCD = -1
        case default
          GCD = m
      end select
    case(1)
      GCD = 1
    case default
      select case(m)
        case(0)
          GCD = n
        case(:n)!<--THIS IS PROBLEM
          GCD = T_GreCoDi(n-m, m)
        case default
          GCD = T_GreCoDi(m-n, n)
      end select
    end select
  end function T_GreCoDi
```

When compiled it causes the error:

> Error: Parameter 'n' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression

So my question: Is there a way to solve this ( I still want to use case-statement)?

It is easy to avoid this error just by using if-statement instead case-statement but I want to use case- for integrity of my code.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were writing this, I really wouldn't use a `select case` construct.  I'll answer under the assumption that such is necessary as far as it goes, though.

The general answer is that with a case selector, whichever of the forms

- `(n)`
- `(l:)`
- `(l:u)`
- `(:u)`

it takes, each thing there (`n`, `l` or `u`) must be a scalar constant expression.  That's just how Fortran says.  This is why your compiler is complaining.

To retain the `select case` construct something will have to be rewritten.  But what?

Let's look at the specific case here, and at the part

```
select case(n)
  case(0) ...
  case(1) ...
  case default     ! n is an integer not 0 or 1
    select case(m)
      case(0) ...
      case(****)   ! Something here for m<n and m.ne.0
        GCD = T_GreCoDi(n-m, m)
      case default
        GCD = T_GreCoDi(m-n, n)
    end select
  end select
```

There are two options here for `m` not 0.  `(:n)` is selected if (non-zero) `m` is less than or equal to `n`.  The `(default)` is selected if (non-zero) `m` is greater than `n`.  But, the only difference between what is executed is in the function arguments.  This leads to the natural `if` construct

```
      if (m<=n) then
        GCD = T_GreCoDi(n-m, m)
      else
        GCD = T_GreCoDi(m-n, n)
      end if
```

You don't want to do that.  Is

```
      GCD = T_GreCoDi(ABS(n-m), MIN(m,n))
```

better?

```
select case(n)
  case(0)
    select case(m)
      case(0)
        print *, 'both of your numbers are zeros. GCD = -1'
        GCD = -1
      case default
        GCD = m
    end select
  case(1)
    GCD = 1
  case default
    select case(m)
      case(0)
        GCD = n
      case default
        GCD = T_GreCoDi(ABS(n-m), MIN(m,n))
    end select
  end select
```

Honestly, I think this confirms my suspicion that the `case construct` is not the way to go here.

Comment: What a shame. I did not think about ABS function. Thank you for the idea.